Google scholar "merged" my paper with another Author's paper
I recently discovered that my paper shares the same title as another author's work, and unfortunately, Google Scholar has merged the two. When viewing the other author's paper, there are six versions listed, two of which are actually mine. Since the versions are indexed by Google, I'm unable to separate them.
I've attempted to unmerge them within Google Scholar but haven't been successful due to the indexing.
Any help?

Help can only come from them, but most such things are very difficult or impossible, even to reach someone. One of the "benefits" of an AI driven system, I guess.

Automated Intransigence?

Thankfully no one uses google scholar for anything serious so it doesn’t really matter.

@TheDoctor That's definitely not true.

Update - So I sent a message to google support and got the following reply (relevant part):
"As a Google Support Specialist my Expertise is limited to the issues related to limited Google Products.
Upon reviewing your concern, I feel it is a good thought to include a support team for Google Scholar. However, currently we do not have an option you asked for.
I would certainly take this as a feedback, as this constantly helps us in making our services better for our customers. I hope they’ll work on it and come up with something in the future."
